# Angular - Observer map not working as intended

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to fetch data from my backend, creating a class object for each item I get

```js
  getRankingList(type: RankingListType, page: number) {

    let params = new HttpParams().set("pid", String(page)).set("limit", String(5));

    return this.http.get(`http://127.0.0.1:3333/ranking/player/all`, { params })
      .pipe(
        map(item => new RankingGuild(item['guild'], item['name'], item['country'], item['honor'], item['RawKey']))
      );
  }
```

The data I'm receiving from the backend looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "RawKey": "1",
    "honor": 0,
    "guild": "Test",
    "name": "test",
    "country": 1
  },
 {
    "RawKey": "2",
    "honor": 0,
    "guild": "Test2",
    "name": "test2",
    "country": 1
  }
]
```

But instead of iterating through the object, "item" is the object itself, meaning there is only one iteration returning the object that I had in the first place, rather than its entries. I've been searching for hours to find a solution, but it seems like this is the correct way to do it, not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the RxJS [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator and JavaScript's `Array.map()` are 2 different things altogether. You should read up on their differences.

In short, the RxJS `map` operator allows you to apply a given project function to each value emitted by the source Observable, and emit the resulting values as an Observable. On the other hand, the `Array.map()` method merely creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

If you want to map the value returned by the response from the HTTP request, I believe this is what you should be doing instead.

```
getRankingList(type: RankingListType, page: number) {

  let params = new HttpParams().set("pid", String(page)).set("limit", String(5));

  return this.http.get(`http://127.0.0.1:3333/ranking/player/all`, { params })
    .pipe(
      map(response => response.map(item => new RankingGuild(item['guild'], item['name'], item['country'], item['honor'], item['RawKey'])))
    );
}
```

Then, on your component itself, you may subscribe to the method to return the actual values itself.

```
getRankingList.subscribe(res => {
  // do the rest
})
```

Comment: Ahh man I went as far as calling another rxjs map instead of 'response.map'. It worked now, thank you so much!

Comment: @KonstantinSchlegel yes, it is normal and alright to use them together :)

Answer (score 1):

The rx `map` operator is not the array `map` operator. The array `map` transforms items in an array, the rx `map` transforms items in a stream, and the item in the stream in this case is an array. Do this:

```
return this.http.get(`http://127.0.0.1:3333/ranking/player/all`, { params })
  .pipe(
    map(items => items.map(item => new RankingGuild(item['guild'], item['name'], item['country'], item['honor'], item['RawKey'])))
  );
```

Use the array `map` inside your rx `map`.